# Problems setting phone ringtone

Tags: android, ringtone

I am attempting to make an Android program set the phone's ringtone. When I run the below code once, the ringtone is set correctly and works just fine. However, if I run the code more than once, the ringtone becomes silent. Any help in figuring this out would be extremely appreciated.

```
    void setRingtone() {
    //File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //File file = new File(path, "ringtone.mp3"); 


    File file = new File("/sdcard/", "ringtone.mp3");
    Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.*****.*****/" + R.raw.*****);
    ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "my ringtone");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/oog");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

    try {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
    } catch (Throwable t) {}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri adds the file path to a database with the identification as a ringtone. Since the file path was already in the database, there is some error and the value becomes null (if i understand correctly). That is why it only works the first time after setting. To fix this you need to delete the reference first. Here is the code to do so.

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA 
+ "=\"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
```